# How to know which tab is open?

Tags: jquery, zendesk

I'm trying to build a Grease/TamperMonkey script that will let my use a keyboard shortcut that will extract the customer email from my Zendesk app open a new browser tab and direct it to `mycompany.com/customers?email=abc@123.com.`

My problem is that in Zendesk you can have many "tabs" inside of the application, and if I try to grab the email class with `$(".email")` and there are more than one tab open, jQuery will automatically grab the first one.

So I do find which tab is currently in active view?

Comment: (general answer, not specific to Zendesk) Look for an active class for the active tab. Ex: $('.tab.active .email')

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the `:visible` selector to check if its open?  You can target any element and check if it is visible with something like the following:

```
$('.tabcontent').is(':visible');
```

Assuming the following html structure:

```
<div class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
```

The above jQuery expression would return `false`.  Hopefully you can take this example and translate it to suit your needs :)